# Not loaded \selectlanguage*{spanish}

Tags: errors, miktex, languages, miktex-update, update

I have installed the recent version of MiKTeX on OS Windows 11, last update: 12/02/2022, last week and I have a problem. It had never happened to me before. If I write this minimal working example like this

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
 \begin{document}
 alpha
 \end{document}
```

I receive always the following message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.11.25) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/sebys/OneDrive/Desktop/new question/Test3.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size12.clo))
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))

(C:\Users\sebys\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def) (C:/Users/sebys/OneDrive/Desktop/new question\Test3.aux
! Not loaded.
\selectlanguage ...ing it}\errmessage {Not loaded}
                                                  
l.2 \selectlanguage
                    *{spanish}
?
```

**.aux file.**

```
\relax 
\selectlanguage *{spanish}
\@writefile{toc}{\selectlanguage *{spanish}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

**What has happened?**

Related old question: [Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option spanish yet. Deleting .aux does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258753/package-babel-error-you-havent-loaded-the-option-spanish-yet-deleting-aux-do)

**How should it be solved?**

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (I tested your MWE as is  in new file), however, you not load `babel`.

Comment: show the complete log?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No .log file is generated. The process is stopped. I can put the complete compilation listing and the .aux file.

Comment: @Zarko Ok, I will not load any babel.

Comment: Presumably the minimal example is too minimal and the problem only occurred in your tests only because of commands left over from previous runs in the temporary files (`.aux` or possibly one of the `.lo...` files). Does the MWE reproduce the error for you when you run it in a new, empty folder?

Comment: @moewe I have removed all the auxiliary, temporary files that were in the folder related to the file and everything works correctly. Inside the folder I have other .tex files with the .log and .aux files that are not disturbing. For me your comment solves everything and the question can be closed.

Comment: a log is always generated, but here simply delete the .aux

Comment: you probably compiled something using polyglossia earlier. Simply delete the aux and recompile.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't find it :-( sorry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hi, you're right I have compiled something using polyglossia for an user. I have removed all and all work correctly.